# Why are new products not showing?

Tags: magento2, indexing

> Note: I'm aware of the [existing question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163688/magento-2-new-added-products-not-showing). This is a different, more specific question.

A bigger multi-store setup recently stopped to show new products unless I run
`bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

After investing I came across [this bug report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5836#issuecomment-350099815). It turned out that the cron-job *does* actually properly index the new product (it shows up in the corresponding index tables). So the problem shouldn't lie with the indexer. When I set indexing to *Update on save* by running
`bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime`
everything works as expected. Of course that's not a permanent solution. Neither is reindexing for every added product.

I assume that `indexer:reindex` also clears cache tags so I figured it might actually be a cache problem. Flushing or deactivating the cache didn't do anything, though.

I would appreciate any pointers on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

When you import products product data was not inseted in cataloginvetory-stock (stock related) data not that table

And when you trying to display data without reindexing
Its all check in foreach($productcollection as $product)
(Is in stock or not, availablity, salebale)
All the thing

So when you reindex it  then this all the data will be inserted on perticulars product tables that why

Comment: I'm adding the products via the regular Magento2 Backend which worked until two weeks ago and just stopped working now. The stock-info is also properly added when adding the new product.